# If $(v_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence in $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, what we can say about weak convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $1<p<N$ and consider the Banach space $Y=W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ equipped with the norm
$$\|u\|_Y :=\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)} +\|u\|_{\infty}\quad \mbox{ for any } u\in Y.$$

My question is: if $(v_n)_n\subset Y$ is a bounded sequence in $Y$, I can say that:

1. a renamed sequence $(v_n)_n$ and $v\in Y$ exists such that $v_n\rightharpoonup v$ in $Y$?

or

2. a renamed sequence $(v_n)_n$ and $v\in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ exists such that $v_n\rightharpoonup v$ in $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

or

or either of them?
Could someone please tell me what I can say about a bounded sequence in $Y$?

There was a severe discussion in my math class but we didn’t get to the bottom of it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $(v_n)_n$ is bounded in $Y$ it is bounded $W^{1,p}$ and since $W^{1,p}$ is reflexive its closed unit ball is weakly compact (Kakutani's theorem) yielding a weakly convergient subsequence.

Comment: @dennis_s thank you for your comment. So, since $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is not reflexive, we can not say that $v$ belongs to $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, isn't it?

Comment: Not quite, but possibly. I would expect that $Y$ is dense in $W^{1,p}$ since $L^1\cap L^\infty$ is dense in $L^2$ w.r.t. the $L^p$ norms, so one couldn't use the fact that closed subspaces of reflexive spaces are reflexive.

Answer (score 2):

$W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$ for $1<p<\infty$ is reflexive, so there is a subsequence that converges weakly to some $v_1 \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$.

$L^\infty(\mathbb R^N)$ is the dual of the separable space $L^1(\mathbb R^N) $,  so there is a subsequence that converges weak-star in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^N)= L^1(\mathbb R^N)^*$ to some $v_2\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^N)$.

Now we have a subsequence $(v_{n_k})$ such that $v_{n_k} \rightharpoonup  v_1$ in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$ and $v_{n_k} \rightharpoonup^* v_2$ in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^N)= L^1(\mathbb R^N)^*$.

Let me argue that $v_1=v_2$: Take $R>0$, and consider the restrictions of all these functions to the ball $B_R(0)$.
It should be easy to check that both modes of convergence imply
weak convergence in $L^p(B_R(0))$, i.e., $v_{n_k}\rightharpoonup  v_1$ in $L^p(B_R(0))$ and $v_{n_k} \rightharpoonup v_2$ in $L^p(B_R(0))$.
Hence, $v_1=v_2$ on $B_R(0)$. Since $R$ was arbitrary, it follows $v_1=v_2$.

Comment: daw, thank you for your answer. Actually, I am not interested in weakly-$*$ convergence, so I will put aside that part of your answer for a minute. So, my question is: if I am not interested in weakly-$*$ convergence, I can say that $v\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ exists such that $v_{n_k}\rightharpoonup v$ in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, isn't it? Possibly it would be $v\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ too, but I need to prove it but using other ideas, isn't it?

Comment: yes to your first question. To get $v\in L^\infty$ the easiest way is to use weak-star convergence.

Comment: daw, may I ask you what do you mean with "To get $v\in L^{\infty}$ the easiest way is to use weak-star convergence?"

Comment: By the weak-star convergence you get that $v_{k_n}$ converges weak-star to some $g$ in $L^\infty$. Then you can show that $g=v$ a.e.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. this is something "standard"? Where I can find a proof?

Comment: I would be grateful to @daw if would add these details.